# Edit AxesLabel from an existing plot

Tags: plotting, editing

I have a really complex function that takes a few hours to plot as a function of a parameter.
Few days later I realised that I named the axes wrong. Is there an easy way to edit the AxesLabels without running the plot again? (it takes too long!!)
I tried `Show[%, AxesLabel-> {newname, newname2}]` but it doesn't change anything...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Very straightforward:

```
plot = Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}];

plot /. (AxesLabel -> _) -> (AxesLabel -> {"x", "y"})
```

Answer (score 2):

You can copy and paste your graphic, add `/. {"oldName1" -> "newName1", "oldName2" -> "newName2"}` after it, and evaluate :

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want?

```
g = Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 \[Pi]}]
Graphics[Line@Cases[g, Line[x__] :> x, \[Infinity]], PlotLabel -> "New labels", Options[g]]
```